# update statement in c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

Anyone knows why tihs code doesn't work?
Program says "Invalid use of null".
In access thise code is working, but not hire. `UPDATE cas SET cas.skupaj = CDbl([Odhod]-[Prihod])*24;`

```
try
{
    OleDbConnection conn = GetConnection();
    conn.Open();

    String MyString = @"UPDATE cas SET skupaj = CDbl(Odhod-Prihod)*24 " ;  

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(MyString, conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Uspešno dodano v PB!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This is really confusing.  The error message `Invalid use of null` is an Access error message.  How are you getting that in C# code?  When you say this works in access, that means you can run that exact SQL statement above in Access without any errors?

Comment: Might be due to NULL value for any one of column (Odhod-Prihod), AS CDate cannot handle Null values.

Comment: Code that HansUp posted it is working. In querry must be where is `Odhod Not Null and Prihod Not Null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an Access Immediate window session, these statements throw error 94, *"Invalid use of Null"*.

```vb
? CDbl(Null)
? CDbl(10 - Null)
? CDbl(Null - 10)
? CDbl(Null - Null)
```

Revise your query to make sure you don't give `CDbl()` Null values.

```sql
UPDATE cas
SET skupaj = CDbl(Odhod-Prihod)*24
WHERE
        Odhod Is Not Null
    AND Prihod Is Not Null
```

OTOH, it's not clear why you need to store that calculated value to `skupaj`.  You could use a `SELECT` query to return it whenever you need, and that way you wouldn't have to run the `UPDATE` again whenever `Odhod` or `Prihod` values change.

```sql
SELECT CDbl(Odhod-Prihod)*24 AS skupaj
FROM cas
WHERE
        Odhod Is Not Null
    AND Prihod Is Not Null
```